# How to Convert 8 bit to 16 bit?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string to 1 and 0 equivalent to the ASCII value of each character of String, its a kind of encoding. My code is giving me 8 bit results and I need 16 bit results for every character e.g. if my input string is 1A, then i am getting 0011000101000001 but desired output is 00000000001100010000000001000001. I want to have 8 extra zeros to make it 16 bit code. **I am not suppose to use any third party method.** Please give your suggestion on how to make it 16 bit. Also share your views on whether it is possible to decode the 16 bit back to 1A

```
  try(FileReader f=new FileReader(myFile)) 
    {

      int i;
      while((i=f.read())!=-1)
      {
      char c = (char)i;
      String s = Character.toString(c);

      byte[] bytes= s.getBytes();
      StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

      for (byte b : bytes)
      {
         int val = b;
         for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
         {
            binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
         }
      }
      System.out.print(binary);
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the encoding?

Comment: You should probably tag this question as homework.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Base 10 to Base 2
 yes it is a very small part of a very big homework and i am not able to move forward without having 16 bits.

Comment: Is `getBytes(..)` allowed even? Sometimes homework assignments are .. icky. Anyway, there is *no* base-10 to base-2 conversion going on. The code is printing out the bit-representation of the given byte sequence (which is derived from how ASCII is mapped to such bytes).

Comment: Anyway, consider this before writing each byte's bit pattern: `binary.append("00000000")` ;-)

Comment: Ohh silly i am, it was pretty simple. thanks @user2864740 and good mocking ;)

Comment: @user3002538 Also, as per Marko's answer, make sure to supply an encoding to `String.getBytes` such that the encoding is predictable. ["ISO-8859-1"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) might be appropriate here. See the [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) documentation. Note that "US-ASCII" is *7-bit clean*, but if only ASCII input is allowed then this would be (more) appropriate.

Comment: Sure, I am using UTF-8 here

Comment: No serialization here, removed tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the character encoded in `UTF-16` instead of the (probable) default of `UTF-8`. So, just change this line

```
byte[] bytes= s.getBytes();
```

to

```
byte[] bytes= s.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
```

Comment: thanks, i forget this part...this is working but i am getting undesired additional string on 1s too along with 16 desired bits e.g. 1 is giving 11111111111111110000000000011000 instead of 0000000000011000.. idk how is it comming?

Comment: That's the Byte Order Mark (BOM) character. Use `"UTF-16BE"` to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (byte b : bytes)
{
    int val = b;
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) binary.append(0);
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val <<= 1;
    }
}
```